# Java regular expression, simple

Tags: java

I am struggling to implement the following,

lets say I have string :

```
 ( z )  ( A ( z )  ( A ( z )  ( A ( z )  ( A ( z )  ( A )  )  )  )  )
```

I want to write a regex that takes out all characters that have a braked to their left and right. i.e. I would like this to return:

```
 ( z ) ( z ) ( z ) ( z ) ( z ) ( A )
```

I have tried a combination of regex's like: `(\\s\\S( \\W \\)\\s\\S)`

thanks
daniel

Comment: Just escape the parens. They have special meaning in regex.

Comment: Regex is not suitable for parsing nested structures like this. Writing your own parser for this will give you a better solution. http://stackoverflow.com/a/133684/1583

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This expression should work:

```
Pattern.compile("\\(\\s*\\w+\\s*\\)").matcher(input);
```

Literal parens need to be escaped in the regex and I think you've got a few extra ingredients there. The regex I show allows whitespace before and after the word chars contained within parens.

Comment: ok, not working with this code though:  Matcher regexMatcher = checkRegex.matcher( "\\(\\s*\\w+\\s*\\)" );
    while ( regexMatcher.find() ){   if (regexMatcher.group().length() != 0){    System.out.println( regexMatcher.group() ); }}

Comment: Why didn't you paste the exact expression the way I wrote it? You use a single backslash in front of the paren. That's wrong.

Comment: well, my code doesnt even work if I Do:  Pattern checkRegex = Pattern.compile("s");
    Matcher regexMatcher = checkRegex.matcher("\\w");

Comment: Yes, now I notice it. One passes the **input string** to the matcher and the regex to `Pattern.compile`. You have it the wrong way.